# Create a fractions matrix

Tags: c++, c, matrix, fractions

I'm trying to create a fractions matrix.
First, i create a class Matrix, and define methods, like create a new matrix, delete matrix, solve a matrix (Gauss and Gauss-Jordan method). All the values on the matrix are float. I compile all and works :D. But now, I'm trying to create another matrix, exactly equals to the first, but this need to be only for fractions. This is my problem, how i do this? how i create a method that receives 2 number (for example: `myMethod(2,3)`), regards these like 2/3 and puts in a matrix position? My goal is have something like that:

Matrix:

```
1/2   2/3   1/5

2/5   3/4   3/2

2/7   3/5   1/3
```

All the numbers will be sent by the user, for example, `cin>>n1>>n2;` (Actually this is `n1/n2`)

PD: i was thinking on create a for loop like:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    myMethod(n1,n2);
```

PD2: Sorry for my english, i hope you understand me :(

Comment: You can create a class for operating with fractions and keep the objects of this class in special matrix class.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, c++ cannot handle fractions natively. the best you could do is float. Alternatively, if you just would like to display the Matrix as a fraction (and maybe do some operations on it), you could do something like the following.

```
Mat numerator[3][3];
Mat denominator[3][3];
cin>>numerator[0][0]>>denominator[0][0];
//.... for all elements

//Display
cout<<numerator[0][0]<<"/"<<denominator[0][0];

//operations
newmatrix[0][0] = numerator1[0][0]*numerator2[0][0] / (denominator1[0][0]*denominator1[0][0]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks :) But  i resolve the problem finally. I read the numbers and then I divide them, thats throwme a decimal number, this decimal number was in the matrix, i solve the operations in the matrix and finally, the decimal numbers are converted in fractios, BTW, I going to post the final program later :]

Comment: sorry for the english, i cant sleep last night and google translator its a sh** c:

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename NumberType>
class Matrix {
   // ...
}:
```

And think about mathematical operations on each supported number type.